# Instantiate one Routebuilder from inside a route in another RouteBuilder in Camel

Tags: apache-camel

I am relatively new to Camel. I have a use case where I need to instantiate a RouteBuilder only when it receives get an exchange to kickstart the process from an Orchestration module. I am trying to do this mainly because, the exchange carries information required to instantiate the new `RouteBuilder`. Is there a way where I could instantiate this new `RouteBuilderB` from inside a route in the existing `RouteBuilderA`.

```
public class RouteBuilderA extends RouteBuilder {

    public void configure(){

        //So, something like this?


        from("direct:A")

        .process(//new RouteBuilderB())

        .to("direct:B")
    }
```

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

Yes its just Java code, so write a `Processor` that creates the `RoutBuilder` instance you want, and do any configuration with setter/getter etc. And then you can add that as routes to `CamelContext` using the `addRoutes` method.